# How to copy a List of key value except 1 key in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have 1 List of key:value pair primaryList in Java, now i want to copy complete list except one key date in primaryListExceptDate. Can anyone help me on this? I know we can do it using for loop but i want to know is there any other efficient way of doing it?

Comment: i have tried for loop but that is not efficient way.

Comment: no, show us some code. It is a little hard to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve just by reading your unclear text there.

Comment: Copy all and then remove one

Comment: You can use `Stream` with `filter` and `map` methods

Comment: what kind of list are you using ? Have you considered to use other data structure (map for example ?).
Without further assumption on the data i don't think your problem can be resolved in less than O(n) time.

Comment: Use a `Map` and check this example out https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples/

Comment: how come your list is key - value pair? are you sure it is not a map? could it easily become a map? Another angle: is your list sorted on those dates? `Collections.binarySearch()` for `ArrayList` is efficient, so you could find your date and remove that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I understand you, you have a list of `Record` objects that keep pairs of values as key, value!?

Then you can use `Stream` api to do what you want. Something like:

```
List<Record> primaryListExceptDate = primaryList.stream()
   .filter(record -> !record.getKey().equals(unwantedDateInstance))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That will give you a new list without the `Record` with that unwanted date.

**UPDATE**: You asked for a `Vector` example.

I made this test which works fine, d2 is removed. `Vector` implements `List` so it can be cast. `Collectors` doesn't have a `toVector` method since `Vector` is outdated:

```
public class Testa {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date d1 = new Date(100,1,2);
    Date d2 = new Date(101,2,3);
    Date d3 = new Date(102,3,4);
    Date test = new Date(101,2,3);

    Vector<Record> primaryList = new Vector<>();
    primaryList.add(new Record(d1, new Object()));
    primaryList.add(new Record(d2, new Object()));
    primaryList.add(new Record(d3, new Object()));

    List<Record> primaryListExceptDate = primaryList.stream()
               .filter(record -> !record.getKey().equals(test))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());

    primaryListExceptDate.forEach(r -> System.out.println(r.getKey().toString()));
}

static class Record {
    Date key;
    Object value;

    public Record(Date k, Object v) {
        this.key = k;
        this.value = v;
    }

    public Date getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah it worked fine for lists but what if we have Vector<Record>?

Comment: Hi, what will be the change for vector, ".collect(Collectors.toList());" is throwing me error.

Comment: BTW: don't use Vector, use List instead (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386288/181336)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's more efficient but you could first make a copy of the list and then iterate over it with an iterator and remove the entry with key 'date'.

EDIT: something like this:

```
List<Record> primaryList = ...;
List<Record> primaryListExceptDate = new ArrayList<>(primaryList );
Iterator<Record> it = primaryListExceptDate.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Record record = it.next();
    if (record.getKey().equals("date")) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: How to remove entry with key 'date'?

Answer (score 0):

Try a foreach construct to copy data into another List with an if to exclude the object that not interest to you. You may think it's not such an efficient way, but most of the methods the API offer have O(n) complexity.
I think it's the simplest method. You also could use List proper methods to copy the List and then remove the object, but this could be a bit more onerous if you look at performance.

Anyway, I suggest you to use Map Collection: it comes to rescue of you when using a key:value pair and it's very efficient! List is useless in this case.

Comment: suppose my list is List<Records> and i want to copy in List<RecordsExceptDate> then can you give me the exact code?

Comment: For example you could use, if "list" is the List<Records> and list1 is List<RecordsExceptDate>:

for(Records elem:list){
   if(elem is not the elem that you want to remove){
      list1.add(elem)
}
}

Comment: i didn't understand what r u trying to say here? can you write the code for my case?

Comment: In the if you'll have to put your custom condition :-)

Comment: How can i get key from elem?bcz i have to put condition on my key.

Comment: It depends on the way you put key:value pair on your list. How did you do this?